# jquery.children works only for the first child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I want to `.slideToggle()` slide class on click of each parent,therefor I'm using `.children()` to access it.but as you see in the snippet it works only for the first div!!

I also have used `.find()` instead of `.children()` but in vain.:(
I appreciate it if someone can tell me my problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#open").click(function() {
       $(this).children('#slide').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body{
 background-color:#ecf0f5;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
.divider {
  height: 1px;
  width:100%;
  display:block; /* for use on default inline elements like span */
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  margin-top:2px !important;
}
.pointer{
 cursor:pointer;
}.slide{
 background:#e2e2e2;
 padding:20px;
 display:none;
 margin:10px;
}.full{
  width:100%;
}.width{
  width:90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full pointer" style="background:#f4f4f4;display:inline-block;padding:7px 14px;margin:0;" id="open">
<input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.15);" /><br>
<div class="slide width" id="slide">
txt
</div>
</div>                            
<div class="divider" style="margin:0;"></div>
<div class="full pointer" style="background:#f4f4f4;display:inline-block;padding:7px 14px;margin:0;" id="open">
<input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.15);" /><br>
<div class="slide width" id="slide">
txt
</div>
</div>                            
<div class="divider" style="margin:0;"></div>
<div class="full pointer" style="background:#f4f4f4;display:inline-block;padding:7px 14px;margin:0;" id="open">
<input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.15);" /><br>
<div class="slide width" id="slide">
txt 
</div>
</div>                            
<div class="divider" style="margin:0;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same `id` multiple times is invalid. Use `class`es for the js part and it will work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open").click(function() {
    $(this).children('.slide').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Check this out and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open").click(function() {
    $(this).children('.slide').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #ecf0f5;
  font-family: IRANSans;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.divider {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  /* for use on default inline elements like span */
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  margin-top: 2px !important;
}
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slide {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
.full {
  width: 100%;
}
.width {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full pointer open" style="background:#f4f4f4;display:inline-block;padding:7px 14px;margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.15);" />
  <br>
  <div class="slide width" id="slide">
    txt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divider" style="margin:0;"></div>
<div class="full pointer open" style="background:#f4f4f4;display:inline-block;padding:7px 14px;margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.15);" />
  <br>
  <div class="slide width" id="slide">
    txt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divider" style="margin:0;"></div>
<div class="full pointer open" style="background:#f4f4f4;display:inline-block;padding:7px 14px;margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.15);" />
  <br>
  <div class="slide width" id="slide">
    txt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divider" style="margin:0;"></div>
```

Comment: Yeap!Now it works fine.thank you...But I still can't figure out why should I use class instead of id!

Comment: because `id`is a unique attribute for a DOM element and in your HTML there were multiple

Comment: @kukkuz Note, there appear to be duplicate `id`s at `html` at stacksnippets?

Answer (score 1):

[`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) of element in `document` should be unique. Substitute using `class` for `id` at both `#open` and `#slide` duplicate `id`s at `html` and selectors, e.g., `.open`, `.slide` at `javascript`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".open").click(function() {
    $(this).children(".slide").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #ecf0f5;
  font-family: IRANSans;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.divider {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  /* for use on default inline elements like span */
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #9b9b9b;
  margin-top: 2px !important;
}
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slide {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
.full {
  width: 100%;
}
.width {
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full pointer open" style="background:#f4f4f4;display:inline-block;padding:7px 14px;margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.15);" />
  <br>
  <div class="slide width" class="slide">
    txt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divider" style="margin:0;"></div>
<div class="full pointer open" style="background:#f4f4f4;display:inline-block;padding:7px 14px;margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.15);" />
  <br>
  <div class="slide width">
    txt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divider" style="margin:0;"></div>
<div class="full pointer open" style="background:#f4f4f4;display:inline-block;padding:7px 14px;margin:0;">
  <input type="checkbox" style="-webkit-transform:scale(1.15);" />
  <br>
  <div class="slide width">
    txt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divider" style="margin:0;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir.You just lost the time...Would you please tell me more about the reason of using class instead of id??

Comment: @Mr.NaViD Have you reviewed link at Answer? `id` of an element should be unique in `document`. _"The `Element.id` property represents the element's identifier, reflecting the [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) global attribute."_

It must be unique in a document,"_

Comment: Sorry!I didn't pay attention to that link.I understood the reason.Thank you